# Is this motherboard dead?

Tags: laptop, motherboard

A friend of mine attempted to clean her laptop, but now it won't even run. She mentioned seeing a spark and sent me these pictures. Could this mean that some components are fried and broken? Or could there be other reasons why this thingy looks odd and the laptop won't start?

[image]

Comment: That surface cap (?) is dead, indeed.

Comment: Tell your friend it is time for a new machine. The motherboard is not worth replacing and likely cannot be repaired.

Comment: @John It very likely CAN be repaired and for very cheap, if that surface component is the only thing that failed (I suggest you watch the TronicsFix YT channel to understand how often catastrophic failure, i.e., doesn't power up, is much simpler to solve that other weird, subtle and/or intermittent problems). But certainly NOT  by someone that needs to ask this question!

Comment: @ChanganAuto, Absolutely agree it's worth a try to fix , and would do so myself -- with the *caveat* that those might not be the only parts destroyed. Likely, there was contact made between these parts and the grounded connector shell, and another part or fuse from V+ line blew.

Comment: She saw sparks, how did she see sparks, if the motherboard was in a laptop case? Sounds like the machine was improperly powered on while it was disassembled